# What causes an IIS recycle in classic asp?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I was wondering if anyone knows what could potentially cause a IIS recycle with a classic asp site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of things can cause IIS to recycle, depending on your IIS settings.  Memory used, time-since-last-recycle, number of requests, and simple schedules can all be used to trigger recycles, as well as crashing modules.  For IIS 6, this page describes the settings that control recycling: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/332088.